# How do I view wordpress themes without logging in?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

Many times I want to show a client how their site is progressing or show someone my current work on a theme to get feedback. I would like a way to send a link possibly with ?theme=.... in the URI that doesn't require a log in.

Currently I have to log in to show the client or others to show progress and get feedback.

Any known ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could solve you problem.
Works with a sidebar which you could set temperarly
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-switcher/

this one works with ?preview_theme=my-theme
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-preview/

Comment: The second one worked like a charm. I looked at it the other day but wasn't sure if it would work. Thanks janw.